# Get executable Windows 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, modern-ui

I am developing a Windows 8 app (Modern UI) and I was asking if I could get the 'executable' of the app to install and test it in other computers without submitting the app to the market.
I am using the visual studio 2012 ultimate, if it helps.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the project and choose Store - Create App Package and deselect uploading to the store. This will create a folder with the package for your app and all dependencies. Use the powershell script, which is also located in the folder to install the app.  Normally if you run it for the first time it will probably ask you to change your ExecutionPolicy, but then it will install the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can sideload an application on another machine without requiring the application be in the Windows Store.

One way, mentioned by Kai in another response to this question, leverages a developer license on the targeted machine. Because this mechanism uses a developer license it's not a suitable method for distributing apps for several reasons:

1. The license states "You may use the developer license only for the purpose of developing, testing and evaluating apps"
2. A [developer license has a 30 (or 90 day) limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974578.aspx), after which the user will be re-prompted to renew the license; that's not a suitable experience for a 'finished' app.
3. Acquiring the license requires an internet connection, so the app may not start if offline.

The approved mechanism for distributing applications to the end-user outside of the Windows Store is via Windows 8 Enterprise or by purchasing enterprise side-loading activation keys for devices not running Enterprise (like RT).  Some [information on this process can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation-results.aspx?Category=Applications).